# Combine three map which has the same keys

Tags: java

I am trying to get all file names, file size and last modified time. I am using a stream to collect them. See the below codes. However, the way I am thinking needs three maps. {File: fileName} {File: fileSize} {File: fileLastMod}. Is there any way that I can use Stream to collect into one map like {"name":fileName, "size": fileSize, "time":lastMod} PS: I think I can use a Class to solve this. I am thinking if I can do it in a stream.

```
RegexFileFilter fileFilter;
    // if extension is "*" then shows all the file
    if (exe.equals("*")) {
         fileFilter = new RegexFileFilter(".*\\..*");
    }else{
        fileFilter = new RegexFileFilter("\\." + exe);
    }

    ObservableMap<File, String> fileNameMap = FXCollections.observableMap(
            FileUtils.listFiles(targetDir, fileFilter, FileFileFilter.FILE)
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(identity(), File::getName)));

    Map<File, Long> fileSize = FileUtils
            .listFiles(targetDir, fileFilter, FileFileFilter.FILE)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(identity(), FileUtils::sizeOf));

    Map<File, Long> fileLastModifyTime = FileUtils
            .listFiles(targetDir, fileFilter, FileFileFilter.FILE)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(identity(), File::lastModified));
```

Comment: You can combine streams via `Stream.concat` and collect once. `Stream.concat(FileUtils.listFiles(...).stream(), FileUtils.listFiles(...).stream())`

Comment: If you want a minimal view of that information, you can rather merge the values into a custom object(define a class with those attributes) and perform that operation with a single stream.

Comment: aside - on the choice of keys in the map, would you do lookups based on the complete `File` object and not any specific attribute? If so, then [the contradictory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470470/1746118) is much more applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create your own class:

```
class FileInfo {
    private String name;
    private long size;
    private long lastModified;

    // constructors, getters, setters, hashcode, equals etc. omitted for brevity
}
```

And then change your 3 `Stream`s to this single `Stream`:

```
Map<File, FileInfo> map = FileUtils
    .listFiles(targetDir, fileFilter, FileFileFilter.FILE)
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        identity(), 
        file -> new FileInfo(file.getName(), FileUtils.sizeOf(file), file.lastModified())
    ));
```

Comment: This is how I would do it.  Especially since the values are of different types.  Otherwise, one would need a List<Object> .

Answer (score 4):

Why so complex? All the information you need is contained by the [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class itself.

A simple `List<File>` would already fulfill your needs. You actually just store redundant information into these maps, which serve no additional purpose.